# Why textured physics body in sprite kit does not react to the collision?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, xcode6, game-physics

I have created this sprite:

```
- (SKNode *) createPlayer
{
    SKTextureAtlas *spritesAtlas = [self textureAtlasNamed:@"sprites"];
    SKNode *playerNode = [SKNode node];
    [playerNode setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))];
    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[spritesAtlas textureNamed:@"alien"]];
    [playerNode addChild:sprite];
    playerNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:sprite.texture size:sprite.texture.size];
    playerNode.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    playerNode.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    playerNode.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    playerNode.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0f;
    playerNode.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;
    playerNode.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.0f;
    playerNode.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0f;
    playerNode.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    playerNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategoryPlayer;
    playerNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
    playerNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CollisionCategory1 | CollisionCategory2 | CollisionCategory3 | CollisionCategory4 | CollisionCategory5;
    return playerNode;
}
```

If in physics body definition I use some shape, such as circle, it indeed reacts to the collision. However, if I try to use the precise shape as in the code above, it just goes past everything. Why is that and how can I fix it? (The pictures are .png with transparent background)

Comment: Setting the collisionBitMask of a physics body to 0 will make it pass though all other physics bodies.

Comment: Why ? If I leave it as a circle instead of texture, it doesnt pass

Comment: No idea but does setting the collisionBitMask to `0xFFFFFFFF` (all categories) solve your problem?

Comment: Just tried, it does not

Comment: If you haven't already, add skView.showsPhysics = YES; in your GameViewController (viewDidLoad method) and see if you are getting a physics body for the playerNode.

Comment: Just tried it, it does not. maybe something is wrong with my picture format? Its adobe illustrator generated png file, saved using artboard and transparent background